Specify path to golangci-lint executable in vsCode Go extension
I'm working on a shared Go repo. The repo includes a committed executable for golangci-lint, so that we can all run the same exact version of the linter on local machines and on CI.
I'm also using the vsCode Go extension. I can configure it to use golangci-lint as a linter, but I have not found a way to specify a version. Because the committed version of the executable is 1.56.0 and vsCode installs the latest (1.59.0), the output I get in vsCode is inconsistent with CI and everyone else.
Is there a way to configure the vsCode Go extension so it points to a specific path for golangci-lint?

You could use go.toolsGopath to configure Go tools per workspace.

The problem is that I need to do this specifically for the linter, not for all tools.

Use symbolic links for the other tools then.
